# Atlanta Sitecore User Group - March 27, 2017

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

**Date/Time (EST):** Monday, March 27, 2017, 6:30 PM

**Date/Time (UTC):** Monday, March 27, 2017, 23:30

**Location:** [Roam Buckhead](https://www.google.com/maps?f=q&hl=en&q=3365+Piedmont+Rd+NE,+Suite+1400,+Atlanta,+GA,+us), 3365 Piedmont Rd NE, Suite 1400, Atlanta, GA

**RSVP:** https://www.meetup.com/Atlanta-Sitecore/events/237675642/

**Twitter:** [@AtlantaSitecore](https://twitter.com/atlantasitecore)

Mark your calendars for the next Atlanta Sitecore User Group meeting on March 27, at 6:30 pm, at Roam in Buckhead!

The session will feature presentations on the following topics:

- **Sitecore xDB Personalization and CoveoReveal: The Machine Learning Search Engine** – [Simon Langevin](https://twitter.com/silaouo) from [Coveo](http://www.coveo.com/en/solutions/coveo-for-sitecore?sc_lang=en)
- **Sitecore on Azure PaaS** – [George Chang](https://twitter.com/sitecoregeorge) and [Stephen Tynes](https://twitter.com/stephentynes) from [Perficient](http://www.perficient.com/)

Plenty of time will be available for Q&A as well as networking.

Comment: Got some UTC times for this? :-)

Comment: Yep right up under EST time.

Comment: D'oh......................

Comment: Now created. "Community Bulletin promotion begins in 4 days"